# Instruments-Xcode-Leaks=> [UIImage imageWithData:]

Tags: xcode, memory, memory-leaks, instruments, allocation

New to using Instruments, but figured it would be good to help the performace of my application I am developing.  I am getting Error leaks on the following command, and was wondering if it might be something I am doing wrong, or can I actually deallocate this.

BASICS - a UITableView is loaded - using JSONDeserializer the data is parsed and pushed into a NSDictionary.  the text labels have no leaks, it's my UIImage that is having the leak. (Each tablecell has 1 image, that is loaded through JSONDeserizer that has a valid link (http) for the picture, and the picture is downloaded and then displayed in that specific cell

Here is the coding....

```
cell.myImageView.image = [[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"picture"]]]] retain];
```

any help would greatly be appreciated... thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to retain the object returned with `imageWithData` since the assignment does the retention for you.

Instruments are showing you leak because of that extra retain count increment. Remove the retain and all should be fine.